# mapping error bars to geom_points with position_dodge

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given the dataframe:

```
df1 <- data.frame(F = c(0.200, 0.200, 0.130, 0.130, 0.394, 0.394, 0.067,
                        0.067, 0.591, 0.591, 0.200, 0.200, 0.130, 0.130, 0.394),
                  lci = c(156854, 222629, 112382, 180782, 241555, 284076, 63481,
                          120508, 291506, 315274, 116201, 165269, 83254, 134403,
                          178948),
                  median = c(182955, 259094, 131078, 209884, 281751, 331179, 74039,
                             139238, 339989, 367623, 135226, 191810, 96878, 155431,
                             208302),
                  uci = c(213542, 302074, 152997, 244224, 328853, 386617, 86423,
                          161363, 396857, 429202, 158196, 223485, 113343, 180521,
                          243621),
                  mr =  c("H", "M", "H", "M", "H", "M", "H", "M", "H", "M", "H",
                          "M", "H", "M", "H"),
                  start = c("S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "M",
                           "M", "M", "M", "M"))
```

I would like to overlay error bars. I can do so with the following code, but the error bars do not line up horizontally with the points. How do I make sure the error bars pass the center of the corresponding point?
code:

```
ggplot(df1) +
    geom_point(aes(x = as.factor(F),
                   y = median/1000,
                   shape = mr, 
                   size  = start,
                   color = mr), 
               position = position_dodge(width = 0.2) )+
    geom_errorbar(aes(x = as.factor(F),
                  ymin = lci/1000,
                  ymax = uci/1000),
                  linetype = "solid",
                  width = .1,
                  position = position_dodge(width = 0.2)) +
    theme_classic()
```

[image: link to plot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should bring the aesthetics into the `ggplot` part and leave them out of the `aes` for the `geom`. Then the errorbars will be plotted where the points are plotted.
Using too many aesthetics will matching the different geoms again tricky.

Maybe you can use a facet instead.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df1, aes(x=factor(F), y = median/1000,shape=mr, color =mr)) +
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=.5)) +
  geom_errorbar(
    aes(ymin = lci/1000, ymax = uci/1000),
    width = 0.5,
    position=position_dodge(width=.5)) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(df1, aes(x=factor(F), y = median/1000,shape=mr, color =mr)) +
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=.5)) +
  geom_errorbar(
    aes(ymin = lci/1000, ymax = uci/1000),
    width = 0.5,
    position=position_dodge(width=.5)) +
  facet_wrap(~start)+
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, this is helpful. For various reasons I don't want to use facets. Is it possible to use the size as aes for ONLY the points in ggplot part but not modify the size of the errobars? something like this (but it does not work)

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x=factor(F), y = median/1000, shape = mr, color = mr, 
size = start)) + 
geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=.5)) + 
geom_errorbar( aes(ymin = lci/1000, ymax = uci/1000, size = NULL), 
width = 0.5, position=position_dodge(width=.5)) + 
theme_classic()
```

Comment: Jacob this looks more like an extended or updated question not an answer. You could have edited your question instead. `size` in `geom_errorbar` does not make much sense inside the aesthetics, but you can specify it outside. If you put three aesthetics in `ggplot` the errorbar will not follow anymore and get out of sync. I would leave the `size = start` out. It isn't recommended anyhow, as you have seen in the warnings

Comment: great advice. next time I will place my update in another section. thank you.

Comment: Jacob, if my answer helped you solving the problem you may accept it as answer. If you honor someones effort in helping you may even upvote.

Comment: I accepted the answer. I cant upvote yet as my reputation is still too low